# Select most frequent

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I wounder if its possible to find out using sql the most frequent pairs of numbers which appear in the table. ie: 
I've got few columns populated with numbers:

```
num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6
2      3      4     5     6    7
```

Of course the number of rows is larger but you got an idea.. 
The goal is to display for example 10 pairs of numbers which appeared in rows.

Please let me know if its possible, or I should rather perform a "brute-force" kind of solution.

Regards

Comment: That's not a pair, that's 6-tuple.

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you need SQL Server, MySQL, or both? I ask because a lot of newer users tend to tag their MySQL questions as [tag:sql-server] even though they didn't really mean Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Can you give a few more rows of example data, and what you expect the results to look like?  It's not completely clear if you want the results to display the sets of 6 numbers that appears most frequently in the table, or if the results need to find the pairs of 2 numbers that occur most frequently in each row.

Comment: Adam, the result must include a pair of number which most frequently appear in the result. You can think about them as lottery numbers and you want to get 2 most common which were selected in the past. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, you need to do the following:

1. Unpivot the columns
2. Perform a self-join to get pairs
3. Summarize to get the most common pairs.

Let me give a solution that will work in SQL Server, and with very minor modifications in mysql:

```
with allnums as (
        select id, 1 as col, num1 as num from t union all
        select id, 2 as col, num2 as num from t union all
        select id, 3 as col, num3 as num from t union all
        select id, 4 as col, num4 as num from t union all
        ...
    )
select top x an1.num, an2.num, count(*)
from allnums an1 join
     allnums an2
     on an1.id = an2.id and
        an1.col < an2.col
order by count(*) desc
```

I don't think mysql supports the "with" syntax, so you need to either repeat the subquery twice, put the results in a temporary table, or create a view.

You can also express the same idea with database specific constructs, such as "unpivot" in SQL Server.  This can somewhat simplify the SQL, but not by much.

If you don't have a unique id for each row, then an easy thing to do in SQL Server is to use the row_number() function to assign one, in another "with" statement.  Alternatively, you could possibly just convert all the numbers to character strings and then concatenate them together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT TOP 10 num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Use GROUP BY with all the distinct columns you want in your tuple. Then ORDER BY the COUNT function.  This will get a list of of all the distinct sets of numbers. To limit the number of results, include [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) 10 in the SELECT statement.

NOTE: The original post has both the MySql and sql-server tags. This solution works in SQL Server. In MySql the TOP functionality doesn't exist, and you need to use [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) which has similar functionality. Please refer to the [LIMIT documentation](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm), if you need more information on how to use that.

Comment: That query won't exactly work in mysql.  There you use the LIMIT statement isntead of "top".

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I was in the midst updating my answer to note that TOP doesn't work in MySql when you made your comment. I've corrected it now, and included a link the the LIMIT documentation too.